# XLSX.utils.table_to_book Currency Coming As General

Tags: javascript, js-xlsx

I am doing

```
 XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById(table), { sheet: "Sheet JS", raw: false });
```

Table as an HTML Table. However, one of my columns contains USD ($4.56) but is being read as General type in excel and not as currency. How can i use XLSX.utils.table_to_book and  keep certain columns as currency?

Answer (score 1):

To change a cell's number format, set the z property of the cell to the format you want to use. For example:

```
ws["A2"].z = "$0.00";
```

The formatted text is generally stored in the `w` field as opposed to the `v` field but isn't automatically updated when you change the number format. You can do it manually:

```
delete ws["A2"].w; // delete old formatted text if it exists
XLSX.utils.format_cell(ws["A2"]); // refresh cell
```

Example in the snippet

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById('sheetjs');
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(tbl);


var ws = wb.Sheets["Sheet1"]; //  get the current sheet
console.log(ws["A2"].v); //  default v value '4.56'

ws["A2"].z = "$0.00"; //  format the cell

delete ws["A2"].w; // delete old formatted text if it exists
XLSX.utils.format_cell(ws["A2"]); // refresh cell

console.log(ws["A2"].w); // new formatted cell '$4.56'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.0/xlsx.js"></script>

<table id="sheetjs">
<tr><td>S</td><td>h</td><td>e</td><td>e</td><td>t</td><td>J</td><td>S</td></tr>
<tr><td>$4.56</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```